# How to Convert Dictionary that is in INT (track_no : 1) to String(track_no : '1') in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
song_list=[
    {
        'Track_no': 1,
        'Singer': 'Frank Sinatra',
    }
{
        'Track_no': 3,
        'Singer': 'Maroon 5',
}
]
```

Comment: use a for loop to go through each value and directly use `str()` to convert it

Answer (score 1):

As `list`s and `dict`s are mutable, you can do this:

```
for d in song_list:
    d['Track_no'] = str(d['Track_no'])
```